# Pause css animation

Tags: html, css, animation, slideshow

I made a slideshow in html and css and I want to pause the slideshow when my mouse goes over it. I tried to do this with `-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;`, but this only pauses 1 image and therefor messes up the slideshow. Is there a way to pause all the images on hover?

http://jsfiddle.net/m3q8pe56/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/m3q8pe56/1/

```
#slideshow:hover .photo {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; 
    animation-play-state: paused; 
}
```

When you hover `#slideshow` you will pause all `.photo` within `#slideshow`

Comment: Add some explanation too please :)

Comment: Thanks bro! Does this mean something like: when mouse goes over the div slideshow, pause every instance of .photo?

Comment: @AlexChar I think it is self-explanatory but I somewhat agree with you. This simply sets the state of the animations currently running on your elements to be paused. The selector `#slideshow:hover .photo` is what you were needing too: It selects the `.photo` element if you have the mouse over the `#slideshow` element, thus pausing the animation.