# How to pause animation css?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation I'd like to pause for around 5s midway through. Just when the shadow reaches its full length. I know of animation delay but how do I insert it mid way through the animation or where would I put it? Would stopping it and starting a whole new animation where it left off be the solution?

```css
body {background-color: 
    grey;} 
    .sometext {color: #787878; 
    font-size: 40px; text- 
    shadow: -2px -3px 10px 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 
    2px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 
    0.25);
    font-weight:bolder; text- 
    align: center;} 
  
    .sometext {animation: text. 
    color 10s linear infinite; 
    position:relative; 
    animation- 
    direction:alternate. 
    reverse;} 

    @keyframes text-color 
    {from{text-shadow: -2px -3px 
    10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 
    0.75), 2px 4px 12px rgba(0, 
    0, 0, 0.25);} to {text- 
    shadow: 10px 10px 30px 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 
    30px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 
    0.25);}} 

    .white {position:relative; 
    background-color: white; 
    box-shadow: 10px 30px 30px 
    40px white; width: 20px;  
    left:-1px;top:-110px;opac
    ity:0.1}

    .white {animation: torch 10s 
    ease-in-out infinite; 
    animation-delay: 0s; 
    position:relative;animation. 
    direction: alternate. 
    reverse;} 

    @keyframes torch 
    {from{background-color: 
    grey;} to {background-color: 
    white; box-shadow: 10px 30px 
    30px 40px white; 
    opacity:0.9;}} 


    .sunray {
    height: 200px;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: blur(5px);
    position: relative;
    left: 110px;
    top: -120px;
    }

    .sunray {
    animation: ray 15s linear 
    infinite;
    animation-direction: 
    alternate-reverse; 
    animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    @keyframes ray {
    from {
    transform: translate(-100px, 
    -50px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    color: transparent; opacity: 
    0.1;
    }
    }

    .sunray1 {

    height: 200px;

    width: 3px;

    background-color: white;

    opacity: 0.5;

    filter: blur(5px);

    position: relative;

    left: 0px;

    top: -250px;

    }

    .sunray1 {

    animation: ray1 10s linear 
    infinite;

    animation-direction: 
    alternate-reverse; 
    animation-delay: 0s;

    }

    @keyframes ray1 {

    from {

    height: 2px;

    }
  
    to {

    height: 200px;

    }

    }
```

```html
    

    <div class="sometext">4309 
    Design and Illustration 
    </div>

    <div class="white"></div> 


    <div class="sunray"></div>


    <div class="sunray1"></div>
```

Comment: None of the similar questions on SO helped you at all? There are hundreds found by searching!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pause css animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021299/pause-css-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Use animationPlayState.

You can set it on the CSS with:

```
#WRITE-HERE-THE-ID {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Or you can set it with JS with:

```
document.getElementById('WRITE-HERE-THE-ID').style.animationPlayState='running';
```

For example for your case you can pause it within the animation and resume with an :hover + css or with a javascript method.

However, as you say, maybe it should be a simple solution finish your animation, set as no loop and start another on other condition.

References: [full documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp) and an [example](http://www.tutorialspark.com/css3/CSS3_Animation_Pause_Resume_Demo.php); got it from the second answer to this other question: [Make a pause during infinite CSS3 animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903825/make-a-pause-during-infinite-css3-animation)

Comment: Thanks but want to pause it for  5 seconds

Comment: Listen to the events, place a setTimeout for 5000ms and resume the animation. Or use the first solution from the question I referenced.